# Joining Table using range in foreign key

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I currently have 2 tables which needs to be joined.

The first table is a big table,millions of records. The second is a matching table. I would want to join the 2 table. A table of the intended result is shown below. I would need tips on how to write the SQL in MS-SQL to join the 2 tables. I am able to write it in mysql but need help converting it into ms-sql.

```
Table 1

ID X   Column X
1      X1
2      X2
3      X3
4      X4
5      X5
6      X6
...  ...
the list goes on

Table 2

ID   Column Y
1    Y1
3    Y2
6    Y3
11   Y4


Intended result

ID X   Column X  Column Y
1      X1        Y1
2      X2        Y1
3      X3        Y2
4      X4        Y2
5      X5        Y2
6      X6        Y3
7      X7        Y3
8      X8        Y3
9      X9        Y3
10     X10       Y3
11     X11       Y4
12     X12       Y4
```

Working MYSQL Code that needs help converting into MS-SQL

```
SELECT idX, columnX, columnY
FROM (
    SELECT id, columnY, @prevID AS prevID, @prevID := id
    FROM table2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevID := NULL) init
    ORDER BY id DESC) AS t2
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.idX >= t2.id AND (t2.prevID IS NULL OR t1.idX < t2.prevID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both databases, you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top 1 Y
        from table2 t2
        where t2.id <= t.id
        order by t2.id desc
       ) as Y
from table1 t1;
```

Of course, in MySQL, you would use `limit` instead of `top`.

Also, the query will run faster in both databases with an index on `table2(id, Y)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks this answer works perfectly. Will create an index on table2 to test out the speed difference